# CakePHP 3 validation params

Tags: validation, cakephp

is right to do this in cakephp 3?

```
$validator
 ->add('FieldName', [
    'RuleName' => [
        'rule' => 'isUnique',
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => null,
        'on' => null,
        'last' => false,
        'message' => null
    ]
]);
```

or should I do it in the following way

```
$validator
  ->requirePresence('FieldName')
  ->notEmpty('FieldName', 'this field is required')
  ->add('FieldName', [
    'RuleName' => [
        'rule' => 'isUnique',
        'on' => null,
        'last' => false,
        'message' => 'this field is required',
    ]
])
```

I need to know if both forms are correct.
or what is the right way and why?

Comment: Your second example.. From cook book - 

When fields have multiple rules, each validation rule will be run even if the previous one has failed. This allows you to collect as many validation errors as you can in a single pass. However, if you want to stop execution after a specific rule has failed, you can set the last option to true:

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, this generate by cake back

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('name', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('name')

        return $validator;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is a very good question Sunil Kumar. You can create rules and verfications in this validator. Like this:

```
$validator
 ->integer('somefield','The code of this field has to be integer.')
 ->add('somefield', [
   'Error:' => [
     'rule' => ['maxLength', 2],
      'message' => 'The max length of this field is 2 integer number.',
        ],
       'Error' => [
         'rule' => ['minLength', 2],
           'message' => 'The min length of this field is 2 integer number.'
        ]   
      ])
      ->requirePresence('somefield', 'This is a required field.')
      ->notEmpty('somefield', 'This field cannot by empty.');



public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
  $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['somefield'], ['message' => 'This value already exists.']));

  return $rules
}
```